# neo4j : extraction of random graphs WITH CONSTRAINT

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

For the extraction of a random graph, I use:

```
// assume already matched to start node n
MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r1
UNWIND r1 as r
WITH r1, last(nodes(r)) as n

MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH r1, apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r2
UNWIND r2 as r
WITH r1, r2, last(nodes(r)) as n

MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH r1, r2, apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r3
UNWIND r3 as r
WITH r1, r2, r3, last(nodes(r)) as n

MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WITH r1, r2, r3, apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r4
RETURN r1 + r2 + r3 + r4
```

but I would like to add a constraint as :

```
MATCH r = (n)-[z:I]-()
WHERE z.grow CONTAINS "xxx"
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r1
```

but it doesn't work. In fact, it works as if there was no constraint.

Also,

```
MATCH r = (n)-[:I]-()
WHERE r.grow CONTAINS "xxx"
WITH apoc.coll.randomItems(collect(r), 10) as r1
```

is not understood.

It is possible to add such a constraint ?

Comment: Excuse-me it works. My problem is in fact to remove the nodes of the last step to avoid a come back.

Comment: If this is no longer a valid question, you should consider deleting it.